# How does java's chars() stream work with reduce? Does it use character encoding?

Tags: java, char, java-stream

There is challenge on code wars to calculate how many times you have to multiply a Long's individual integers against each other before it becomes a single digit. for example

39 -> 3 * 9 = 27 -> 2 * 7 = 14 -> 1 * 4 = 4 // answer is 3

Here is one of the posted solutions -

```
class Persist {
  public static int persistence(long n) {
    int times = 0;
    while (n >= 10) {
      n = Long.toString(n).chars().reduce(1, (r, i) -> r * (i - '0'));
      times++;
    }
    return times;
  }
}
```

I am very confused by the  "(i - '0')" portion of the code. I just learned yesterday that Java's chars() method returns an IntStream which represent the chars so immediately using the reduce makes sense to me. But then it substracts a character which throws me off because it seems to apply that it is working with chars, but then how are they being multiplied together?

I copied the above code and then deleted the character subtraction so that is was a simple reduce statement that I understood, aka

```
n = Long.toString(n).chars().reduce(1, (r, i) -> r * i);
```

and then ran the debugger. The very first loop calculated 3 * 9 as 2907. Where does that answer come from? My best guess is that it has to do with character encoding but then why does subtracting the char '0' fix it?

Comment: `'0'` is decimal `48`, `'1'` is decimal `49`. So `'0' - '0'` equals 0, `'1' - '0'` equals 1 and so on. It basically turns the character into its digit counterpart

Comment: that should be easy to find out, no? `System.out.println((int)'0');`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `char` is just a number in the range [`0`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#MIN_VALUE) to [`0xFFFF`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#MAX_VALUE) with a special meaning when printing or concatenating to a string.

You can easily write

```java
int i = 'A';
```

but also

```java
char c = 65;
```

Both variables refer to the same number, hence,

```java
System.out.println(i == c);
```

will print `true` but when you execute

```java
System.out.println(i);
System.out.println(c);
```

the different variables types will cause selecting different methods with a different interpretation of the values.

You can use `char` values for calculations and always assign them to `int` variables, as their value range fits into the `int` value range, so it’s possible to process a sequence of `char` values with an `IntStream` and save the creation of another specialized Stream class. You only have to care to interpret the result values correctly.

Speaking of encodings, `char` is defined as an UTF-16 unit, so if you want to give it a name, that’s the right one.

For the example of your question, it’s crucial to know that the chars `'0'` to `'9'` have adjacent values in the UTF-16 encoding (it applies to all Unicode encodings), so not only does subtracting `'0'` from `'0'` give you the `int` value `0`, subtracting `'0'` from any char in the `'0'` to `'9'` range will give you the corresponding `int` value. The fact that `'0'`’s encoded value is `48` is not even relevant to this logic.

Mind the existence of the [`codepoints()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/CharSequence.html#codePoints()) method which returns a sequence of Unicode [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) values in the range `0` to [`1,114,111` (`0x10FFFF`)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#MAX_CODE_POINT). For characters in the [BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane), the values are identical to the `char` values, but values outside the BMP are encoded as two UTF-16 units, so it’s easier to process them with the `codepoints()` stream instead.